# Auto convert leads Professional Edition Salesforce

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, lead-conversion, automation, professional-edition

I am working on auto converting leads in the Professional Edition.  Since I cannot use Apex in the professional edition, I can't use apex triggers nor the visual work-flow with the process builder.

Is it absolutely impossible to create lead auto converting logic in Salesforce professional edition? If it is possible, what are some ways to hack this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "impossible," unless you're looking for an absolutely no-extra-cost solution. The three basic solutions are to (a) [get a product on the AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=auto%20convert%20leads), (b) try to negotiate a contract for Apex Code or API access (either will get you close enough), or (c) upgrade to Enterprise, which admittedly is a good deal for all the extra features you get, but cost prohibitive to smaller orgs.

Comment: Hitting this issue now with a client.  I know API access is a standard addon, but you can add Apex code access at a separate cost? I always thought in order to get Apex code you had to upgrade to Enterprise or higher

Comment: @BrianMiller At the time of this answer, I believe the marketing material for Salesforce included Apex as an optional add-on for Lightning Professional Edition. Checking now, I don't see this as an option any longer. Still, it wouldn't hurt to ask your Account Executive if it's available and what the cost would be. Of course, I typically recommend going up to Enterprise if you need that level of automation, since typically, once you have one such need, you tend to start developing others as well.

Comment: Thank you for checking. We've worked out just about all other automation asks with their Process Builders thus far, but worth reaching out to the AE.  I'll post back here if I get an answer about adding Apex capabilities